# Clojure - formatting a table

Tags: for-loop, clojure, formatting

I have a number of XML files that I have successfully worked with to produce a number of counts against a monthly time period although I need to transform it to condense it slightly. The list I have produced is done via a number of for loops as below (for example) and I have output it into a table in the format below:

```
LEVEL1 (for [forloop LVL4_records]
{
    :MONTH(get (split (:date forloop) #"-") 1)
    :LEVEL(:lvl forloop)
})

group-by-date(group-by :MONTH LEVEL1)

LEVEL1_2 (for [forloop2 group-by-date]
{
    :MONTH(:MONTH (first(second forloop2)))
    :LEVEL(:LEVEL(first (second forloop2)))
    :TOTAL(count (distinct (second forloop2)))
})
```

---

MONTH--LEVEL--COUNT

Jan--------01---------10

Jan--------02---------55

Jan--------03---------112

Feb--------01---------23

Feb--------02---------30

Feb--------03---------268

---

What I want to do is organise this into a way that the Months are distinct and the Levels are the main headers like:

---

MONTH--LEVEL 01--LEVEL 02-- LEVEL 03

Jan--------10------------55-------------112

Feb--------23------------30-------------268

---

I'm guessing that I need another loop to run through the different levels and to make the month distinct although I've tried a few things and they're not working... the code up to now works as in the first table so any help here would be much appreciated in reformatting the data into the second style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a tricky thing to do, but it's doable. Here's what I came up with:

```
(def by-level
  {1  {"Jan" 10, "Feb" 23}
   2  {"Jan" 55, "Feb" 30}
   3  {"Jan" 112, "Feb" 268}})

(def by-month
  (reduce (fn [table [level months]]
            (apply merge-with merge table (map (fn [[month count]] 
                                                 {month {level count}}) 
                                                months)))
          {}
          by-level))

; by-month =>
{"Jan" {3 112, 2 55, 1 10}, "Feb" {3 268, 2 30, 1 23}}
```

(This is snowballing off of Albus' answer -- he pointed out that your map should be arranged using the levels as keys, since that's how your XML file is laid out.)

`reduce` is the functional counterpart to a for-loop. We're using it here to iterate through our table (`by-level`) and build up a new table `by-month` starting from an empty map, `{}`. On each iteration, we take one of the entries in `by-level` (for example, `{1 {"Jan" 10, "Feb" 23}}`) and use `map` on each month-count pair to return a list of maps of the form `{"Jan" {1 10}}` (the first number is the level (1) and the second is the count (10)). Then we `merge` these "month to level/count" maps into our table-in-progress. Once we've iterated through each "level" in our original map, we end up with a map of each month to a secondary map of each level and its count.

"`apply merge-with merge`" might look a little weird at first. The reason we have a secondary `merge` operation is that we're dealing with nested maps. If we had just said `apply merge` instead, `"Jan"` and `"Feb"` would be "overwritten" with each pass through the next level, and in the end we would just have something like `{"Jan" {3 112}, "Feb" {3 268}}`. Using `merge-with`, we make it so that if a key like `"Jan"` already exists, we `merge` the existing value for `"Jan"` with the new value -- the values that we're working with are maps like `{2 55}`, so instead of replacing the value we have, we're "adding onto it" by merging in a new map with a new level/count combination.

Now you can obtain individual values from the map using `get`, for example:

```
(get (get by-month "Jan") 3) ;=> 112 (January, Level 3)
```

Or you can leave the `get`s out and simply use the map itself as a function:

```
((by-month "Jan") 3) ;=> 112
```

Answer (score 2):

Take each group of LEVEL from the data here

> MONTH--LEVEL--COUNT
>
> Jan--------01---------10
>
> Jan--------02---------55
>
> Jan--------03---------112
>
> Feb--------01---------23
>
> Feb--------02---------30
>
> Feb--------03---------268

to and convert them into a `map`, from `:COUNT` to `:MONTH`, then print the table through these maps using the format you provided.

e.g. the map should be something like this

```
{:LEVEL 1 :DATA [{:MONTH "Jan" :COUNT 10}
                 {:MONTH "Feb" :COUNT 23}]
 :LEVEL 2 :DATA [{:MONTH "Jan" :COUNT 55}
                 {:MONTH "Feb" :COUNT 30}]
 :LEVEL 3 :DATA [{:MONTH "Jan" :COUNT 112}
                 {:MONTH "Feb" :COUNT 268}]
```

or even

```
{1  {"Jan" 10
     "Feb" 23}
 2  {"Jan" 55
     "Feb" 30}
 3  {"Jan" 112
     "Feb" 268}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I really am a novice at Clojure so I'll have to investigate how to use a map like this

Comment: Ah ok - see the months and counts are dynamic so they can change, obviously as the year continues on the month list will grow and the counts will populate along side them, hence why I am drawing the data in from XML's and counting them along with other stuff. I'll need to work out how to do this dynamically which is why I had originally thought a loop is the best option here

Comment: Yes, `map` is a basic data structure in Clojure, and it can use basically anything you can think of as a key or a value. It fits your requirement here.